# Gunicorn with gevent workers and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn, gevent

I have a server with 4 cores.

When setting up Gunicorn with workers and threads can I assign the same number of workers and threads to the cpu's since they will be doing different things?

for example

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import multiprocessing

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
bind = "127.0.0.1:5000"
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

Or should I instead do this

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import multiprocessing

workers = 2 * 2 + 1
bind = "127.0.0.1:5000"
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
threads = 2 * 2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With worker_class='gevent' setting threads is irrelevant. See the quote from the documentation,

> Since Gunicorn 19, a threads option can be used to process requests in
> multiple threads. Using threads assumes use of the gthread worker.
> [Gunicorn Design](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html)

Also from threads setting documentation,

> This setting only affects the Gthread worker type.
> [Gunicorn Settings](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html)